# How to use flutter ScreenUtil plugin to responsive theme in the MatrialApp widget?

Tags: flutter, responsive-design, widget, themes, font-size

I want to use [flutter_screenutil](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_screenutil) plugin for sizing fonts in the "theme" and "darkTheme" property which is provided in the MaterialApp widget but i got error when i run app.

```
Ensure to initialize ScreenUtil before accessing it.
Please execute the init method : ScreenUtil.init()
'package:flutter_screenutil/screenutil.dart':
Failed assertion: line 31 pos 7: '_instance != null'
```

**I know that [flutter_screenutil](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_screenutil) plugin must be initialized after MaterialApp widget created(becasue it needs MediaQuery), but i need to access flutter_screenutil in the theme of MaterialApp widget , is there any solution to use that in the theme ?**

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: @JaineelMamtora  Yeah, check it in github issue i created https://github.com/OpenFlutter/flutter_screenutil/issues/168